# Sending a PoisonPill to an Actor in Java

Tags: java, scala, actor, akka

I am starting to learn Akka by migrating an existing Java SE app to it. I am using Akka 2.0.3.

At one point I need to send a PoisonPill through the message queue to stop the actors. My actor is instantiated thus:

```
ActorRef myActor = actorSystem.actorOf(new Props(MyActor.class), "myActor");
```

to which I try to send the PoisonPill:

```
myActor.tell(PoisonPill.getInstance());
```

But I get the following compiler error:

```
'tell(java.lang.Object)' in 'akka.actor.ActorRef' cannot be applied to '(akka.actor.PoisonPill$)'
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm running Java 1.6.0_26 in Idea (which I am also learning after a lifetime in Eclipse).

---

Edit:

I have also tried this approach, which is in the documentation, but I get the same compiler error and Idea warns me that the Actors class is deprecated.

```
import static akka.actor.Actors.*;
extractionActor.tell(poisonPill());
```

Comment: +1 for the question's title. I have no idea what it's about but it reads a bit like a scene from a Thriller or Horror movie :-)

Comment: That's very true - I'd never read it like that! Believe me, I'm actually a very nice person in Real Life.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please read the Akka documentation, we've spent a lot of time creating it:

> **PoisonPill**
>
> You can also send an actor the akka.actor.PoisonPill
>   message, which will stop the actor when the message is processed.
>   PoisonPill is enqueued as ordinary messages and will be handled after
>   messages that were already queued in the mailbox.
>
> Use it like this:
>
> ```
>    import static akka.actor.Actors.*;
>    myActor.tell(poisonPill());
> ```

- http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.3/java/untyped-actors.html#PoisonPill

The above approach has been deprecated since 2.0.2, this is the new API:

```
ActorRef ref = system.actorOf(new Props(JavaAPITestActor.class));
ref.tell(PoisonPill.getInstance());
```

The above compiles on my machine so you might have some issue in IDEA? Try to compile it with javac and see if that works.

Comment: Sorry, I should have said, I did read the documentation and I did try that before asking the question, but not only do I get the same compilation error, I am also told that Actors is deprecated, which is why I tried the other approach. I will update my answer.

Comment: Great, thanks, I've edit my answer to reflect both the deprecated and the new API.

Comment: I've moved back to Eclipse and it compiles fine! I suppose it could be a bug in Idea, but it's probably more a case of me doing something wrong in an IDE I don't know that well...

Comment: I'm just glad it ain't a problem in Akka :-)

Comment: I have the same issue. I'm assuming it'd an Idea issue. Compilation and running work fine.

Comment: Yeah, you should try Eclipse :-)

Comment: This is not true anymore, an actorRef is required when calling tell, so you are supposed to pass in the actorRef like so :        target.tell(PoisonPill.getInstance(), ActorRef.noSender());

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned in my reply to the comment above, this does not work in Idea or when using gradle to compile. It is in fact a compilation error since the sender ActorRef is required. I know the previous answers are old, and i'm not sure if this was a change in the api, so for anyone having a similar issue you should be using :

```
target.tell(PoisonPill.getInstance(), ActorRef.noSender());
```

For reference see : http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/java/lambda-actors.html#PoisonPill

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE FROM 25.03.2019**

The good answers from @Viktor Klang and @yash.vyas are a bit out of date. Here is the current working syntax of Scala *2.12.8* and JDK8 (1.8.0_172):

```
val accountB = context.actorOf(Props[BankAccount], "accountB")
accountB ! PoisonPill
```

You could also write:

```
...
accountB ! PoisonPill.getInstance
```

The default call of the tell-Method is also working:

```
...
accountB.tell(PoisonPill.getInstance,ActorRef.noSender)
```